# assigning multiple tasks created by multi instance subprocess to different actors in JBPM

Tags: jbpm, task-management, redhat-bpm

I have a workflow, where I want to add additional approvers during runtime and wait till all the approvers or specified number of approvers approve the task.
Lets say, I have a user task, which says he wants 3 approvals from a particular group.
I am using multi instance sub process to achieve this. Where the process exists when it gets specified number of approvals.
But my problem is that, mutilple tasks are created for the all the users (if I specify 3 required approvals, 3 tasks will be ctreated for all users in the group). I want only one task to be created or assigned to per user in the group and then wait till any 3 users approve it. (a user should not be able to see other task assigned to the group once he approves it ).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have one task completed by multiple users, these are considered different tasks.  In this case, if you assign each task to an individual user, they will only be visible to those people.  Alternative, you could try looping through task approval 3 times but using excluded owners to make sure none of the previous approvers can claim it again.